# Extracting Main Content ( Highest Text Density ) From a news article Web-Page

Tags: java, text, html-parsing, html

I want to make a code to extract the main news from a news website . News websites contain the main news , ads , reviews , copyright notice so i want to get only the main news like done in boilerpipe but i want to know how to do that .

So i want to have information about how is the process for doing this work .

Sudhanshu

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the boilerpipe websites contains source code, quickstart instructions, links to the original scientific paper and to the corresponding conference presentation video:

http://code.google.com/p/boilerpipe/

This should give you a quite comprehensive set of information on how this works and how you can apply this in your scenario.

Best,

Christian

Answer (score 2):

We try a lot of open source crawlers, like Readability, Beautiful Soup etc. for same, but after testing [Diffbot](http://diffbot.com) API we decide use it for AppMarkt. It fast and extract news articles really well from various languages.

Answer (score 0):

[JSOUP](http://jsoup.org/) provides an API for parsing HTML

Answer (score 0):

I would give [htmlcleaner](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/index.php) a try.

> HTMLCleaner is Java library used to safely parse and transform any HTML found on web to well-formed XML. It is designed to be small, fast, flexible and independant. HtmlCleaner may be used in java code, as command line tool or as Ant task. Result of parsing is lightweight document object model which can easily be transformed to standards like DOM or JDom, or serialized to XML output in various ways (compact, pretty printed and so on).

You can use `XPath` with htmlcleaner to get contents within xml/html tags.Here is a nice
     example [Xpath Example](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/05/using-xpath-and-html-cleaner-to-parse-html-xml/)